# Dagger 2 update object in module

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm quite new to DI in general and Dagger in particular. I'm currently having this issue which I haven't managed to find a solution yet. Let's say I have an `AppModule` to provide a Retrofit client with access token put in request header

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPref provideSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return new SharedPref(application);
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AuthInterceptor provideAuthenticationInterceptor(SharedPref sharedPref) {
        return new AuthInterceptor(sharedPref.getAccessToken());
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideHttpClient(AuthInterceptor authInterceptor) {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
            .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DribbbleApi provideClient(OkHttpClient client, Gson gson) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(DribbbleApi.ENDPOINT)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create((DribbbleApi.class));
    }
}
```

Now when the user first uses the app, the access token doesn't exist in `SharedPreference` so I provide them with a default one. But once they login, the access token will be saved to `SharedPreference` but I can't update the `OkHttpClient` to accept new value since the `AuthInterceptor` has been created with default access token at the start of the app.

I was looking at some of the questions having the same problem here but none seems to work in my case. I'm thinking about having this module:

```
public class AuthenticationManager {
    private String accessToken;

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String ac) {
        this.accessToken = ac;
    }
}

@Module
public class AuthenticationModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AuthenticationManager provideAuthenticationManager() {
        return new AuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

and just get the access token and create the Retrofit/OkHttp client on the fly, but this seems not right to me. Anyone has the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Your AuthenticationManager solution looks right to me, or you could go with an `AtomicReference<String>` or general `Holder<String>` class you write.

Your best alternative is to make something like a `@Named("access-token") String` or custom-qualifier-annotated `@AccessToken String` available through the app, with a non-Singleton `@Provides` method that uses module state to always return the most current value, but that has a number of problems too:

1. There's no natural setter here, unlike on your AuthenticationManager. Unless the current value is available through something else in the dependency graph that you can accept in your `@Provides` method, you're going to have to inject your `Module` or something that can access the `Module`'s mutable fields. That doesn't sound easy to understand.
2. Strings aren't mutable, so if you want an object that returns the latest value, you'll always want an `@AccessToken Provider<String>` and never a `@AccessToken String`. Dagger doesn't make it easy to make keys that can only inject providers, so unless you have full control over this codebase or can set up a static analysis check, this will be fragile and easily-misused.
3. You have somewhat-more-limited control over the thread-safety and synchronization of the Dagger solution, whereas your own settable holder has semantics you can define yourself.
4. In unit tests, if you want the value of the Provider to change without creating a custom for-testing Dagger component, you'll have to make a settable Provider class. This looks so much like AtomicReference, Holder, or your AuthenticationManager, you might as well start with one of those.

As a final alternative, if you can represent the state of a Request as a short-lived an immutable object, you might prefer to create one of those with a deliberately-limited lifetime. In this way, you would use short-lived objects instead of Singletons and wouldn't have to worry about updating existing instances later. This might also have attractive retry semantics, if (for instance) you want retries to happen with the old access token but for new requests to be created with a new access token. If this option appeals to you, also look up Dagger subcomponents: you could create a new subcomponent with a new immutable Module for every request, and then have full access to your object graph including access to temporary access tokens and state as far deep as it is needed.

Comment: Very detailed answer, thanks! The reason I said the `AuthenticationManager` solution did not look right is because it increases the complexity of the app. Let's say I have a stack of 4 activities where the user can login in any activity. Now when they login at the top of the stack, when they go back, I have to check the `AuthenticationManager` and recreate the other instance of Retrofit/OkHttp if necessary. This is unfortunately too complicated and could bring more trouble if not done right. That's why I'm looking for a solution which I could utilize singleton for the client.